# Axis2: Port number for transport https has not yet been detected

Tags: https, port, apache-axis

This error appers in the logs in my server. The stacktrace is:

[WARN] Port number for transport https has not yet been detected
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Port number for transport https has not yet been detected
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener.getEPRsForService(AxisServletListener.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisEndpoint.calculateEndpointURL(AxisEndpoint.java:198)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisEndpoint.calculateEndpointURL(AxisEndpoint.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisEndpoint.getEndpointURL(AxisEndpoint.java:63)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.getEndpointURL(AxisService2WSDL11.java:1264)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateHttpPort(AxisService2WSDL11.java:738)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateService(AxisService2WSDL11.java:487)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService2WSDL11.generateOM(AxisService2WSDL11.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.outputInlineForm(WSDLDataLocator.java:131)
    at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.WSDLDataLocator.getData(WSDLDataLocator.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis2.dataretrieval.AxisDataLocatorImpl.getData(AxisDataLocatorImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getData(AxisService.java:2964)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.getWSDL(AxisService.java:1645)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1413)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.handleWSDLRequest(ListingAgent.java:327)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

On the server https is not set but apparently all the requests are on http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons for this error are explained in the following document:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/servlet-transport.html